# C++ | Comparing two arrays using std::mismatch (or another STL alternative)

Tags: c++, arrays, stl, mismatch

I am faced with the task of comparing two c++ arrays that are of `int` data type.  I specifically cannot use any loops (`for`, `while`) of my own, and was encouraged to use an STL function.  I found `std::mismatch()` and it seems to be what I want, but I am unable to get it working with a basic array.

Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>     // cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::mismatch
#include <utility>      // pair

int main()
{
    int a[10] = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19};
    int b[10] = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};

    std::pair<int, int> result = 
        std::mismatch(a, a + 9, b);
    
    std::cout<<result.first<<" "<<result.second<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> error: conversion from 'std::pair' to non-scalar type 'std::pair' requested

I am pretty new to C++, so I don't really know what this means.

Comment: This doesn’t address the question, but the end iterator for an array of 10 elements is `a + 10`, not `a + 9`. Even better, though, use `std::begin(a)`, `std::end(a)`, and `std::begin(b)`. That way, if you change the number of elements in `a` you’ll still get the right end iterator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::mismatch` returns a pair of iterators to the container, not a pair of `int`s. In this case, since you have an array, the iterator type is `int*`.

The simple solution is to deduce the type when calling it instead:

```
auto result = std::mismatch(a, a + 9, b);
```

From c++17, you can name the individual elements of the pair as well:

```
auto [i, j] = std::mismatch(a, a + 9, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::mismatch()` returns a `std::pair` of iterators.  In your example, you are using iterators of type `int*` (an `int[]` array *decays* to an `int*` pointer to its 1st element).  So you need to change your `result` variable from `pair<int, int>` to `pair<int*, int*>`.  And then you need to dereference those iterators when printing their values to `cout`, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>     // cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::mismatch
#include <utility>      // pair

int main()
{
    int a[10] = {1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15,17,19};
    int b[10] = {2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20};

    int *a_end = a + 10;
    std::pair<int*, int*> result = std::mismatch(a, a_end, b);

    if (result.first != a_end)
        std::cout << *(result.first) << " " << *(result.second) << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "no mismatch found" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```